# Il y aurait-il une objection à créer un stackexchange.fr francophone?

Tags: informatique

stackexchange est un service utile. Mais en anglais. Il serait intéressant d'en disposer en français sans avoir à le reconstruire soi-même. Ou connaitriez-vous un logiciel libre (ou projet) qui pourrait y aider ?

Comment: Cette question devrait être posée sur Meta. Et il y a déjà eu des discussions à ce sujet sur Meta. Les mods qui sont là depuis le début pourraient certainement répondre, il me semble que @Gilles a participé à  diverses tentative de sites en français sur SE.

Comment: Je clos la question ici car elle n'a rien à voir avec la langue française. [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) est l'endroit où l'on discute de nouveaux forums sur Stack Exchange. Et il y a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) pour les recommandations logicielles.